# HttpClient not working with international domain name

Tags: c#, .net

when I try to use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient to get a response from a domain that has utf characters I get an exception.

```
The remote name could not be resolved
```

Does anyone know how to work around that or if there's a library that handles that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable IDN parsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882553.aspx) in your app.config. It is off by default.

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think HttpClient does international domain name resolving.

You could implement it yourself following what is said [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#Internationalizing_Domain_Names_in_Applications)

You can also check what chrome does when you ask for `http://Bücher.ch/`

[image]

And you can even notice what happens when you try to copy/paste from URL field, it transforms it automatically to `http://xn--bcher-kva.ch/`